# targeting only safari using javascript

Tags: javascript, safari

Wondering if it is at all possible.

found:

```
<script type="javascript">
isSafari3 = false;
if(window.devicePixelRatio) isSafari3 = true;
</script>
```

on http://dustinbrewer.com/css-hackgetting-safari-to-behave/. but it seemed to target both chrome and safari, i'm assuming it's more of a webkit target. also

```
console.log(isSafari3);
```

returned with a px count, not a boolean value. so i'm not sure what that guy was talking about.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you need to detect Safari?

Comment: i elaborate on the issue in the first answer. thanks @ŠimeVidas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot reliably use the existence of devicePixelRatio to reliably detect just Safari.  It might work today, but nothing is stopping some other browser from implementing that and then your code would be completely broken.

It is generally a bad idea to test for a specific browser.  The smarter thing to do is to test for a particular feature you want to use.  If the browser shows the feature exists, you use it, if not, you use some other fallback mechanism.

Feature detection is much, much easier to maintain because as browsers change, you don't have to continually change your code to tweak the behavior for different versions of each browser.  As browsers evolve by adding support for the latest features, your code automatically adapts to them.

Here's an article about feature detection: http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting.  The [library modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/) contains a lot of feature detection code snippets which you can either use in whole or see how it detects features and use just that specific detection.

Comment: ok, to expand on what i'm trying to accomplish, i'm working on a project that has an optional fullscreen feature. And safari supports true fullscreen, however the css gets all wonky. so i was thinking of trying to detect safari and put some specific code for the situation. guess i'll start looking for another way around it.

Comment: @AdamBickford - Why don't you detect if all the pieces you need for the fullscreen capability exist and if they do, then you can implement that feature regardless of which browser it happens to be.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "all the pieces", but to elaborate even _further_, the fullscreen in both chrome and safari fill up the window exactly as intended. once in fullscreen we have it split down the middle into two sections, using `window.outerWidth/2+'px'` to calculate half the screen. this works perfectly in chrome, however in safari it isn't calculating half the screen, and there is a 2-3 inch bar separating the two halves.

Comment: If you want help debugging that specific feature, you'll have to include code for it and more description of what you're trying to do.  I repeat - it is bad to detect a specific browser.  It is much better to detect if the capabilities you need to make a feature work are present and working.

Comment: @AdamBickford So, Safari does not return the same `window.outerWidth` value as Chrome?

Comment: @AdamBickford - perhaps `window.outerWidth` is the wrong value.  According to this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.outerWidth): `outerWidth represents the width of the whole browser window including sidebar (if expanded), window chrome and window resizing borders/handles` which would not be things that you can split in half.

Comment: were using `'width':windowOuterWidth/2+'px'` to calculate the width of the first half, and `'width':(windowOuterWidth-_outerWidth(self.editor))+'px'` to calculate the remaining. here are some screen shots: [chrome](http://i.imgur.com/f48NA.jpg), and [safari](http://i.imgur.com/wnVXF.jpg)

Comment: @AdamBickford - my point was that I think window.outerWidth is the wrong source of information.  You want a width that only includes the actual viewport, not a width that includes part of the non-content area around the edges as that will naturally be different in different browsers.  I don't have time to research the right value to use right now, but I bet if you find the right width to use, it will work in most/all browsers.

Comment: ok, i'll keep poking around the internet, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

this expression casts the value of window.devicePixelRatio to boolean:

```
isSafari3 = false;
if(window.devicePixelRatio) isSafari3 = true;
```

It returns true in Chrome, and false in Firefox.

consider:

```
window.devicePixelRatio = undefined; // false, null, "", 0

if (window.devicePixelRatio){
// false
}

window.devicePixelRatio = "foo"; 

if (window.devicePixelRatio){
// true
}
```

That aside its probably a poor idea for the reasons mentioned by @jfriend00.